# Why was the "UC Project" aptly named?

Tags: mobile-suit-gundam

In the dub of Gundam Unicorn Episode 3, "The Ghost of Laplace", Full Frontal says

> Universal Century is approaching its hundredth year. The U.C. Project was aptly named, indeed.

at about 19:50.

The only source I could find describing the U.C. Project itself if this Wiki entry: http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/UC_Project. This describes the project as an Earth Federation effort to upgrade the military following the events of Char's Counterattack. According to this source, the Unicorn Gundam is the primary product of the U.C. Project, which is in line with my understanding of the project. Char's Counterattack takes place in 0093 U.C., and since Unicorn takes place in 0096 U.C., the U.C. Project would only be 2 or 3 years old at most.

So what did he mean? Why is it "aptly named"?

Comment: This might help; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Century#Chronology

Comment: I hate to say it, but is it not just because "century" means 100 years? Taken entirely out of context that's how I read the quote.

Comment: @AlanThird I thought of that, but that doesn't seem at all remarkable enough to make note of it. The series is based on a novel. I can't help but wonder if there's more details there, but it's in Japanese. =/

Comment: You see it, don’t you? There you go.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Full Frontal is referring to the fact that the Universal Century was established as part of humanity's space colonization program (see the [Universal Century entry](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Universal_Century) on the Gundam Wikia), and the UC Project would be (in Full Frontal's eyes) the completion of that program by ["rebuilding order in the Earth Sphere"](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/UC_Project).

The UC Project was meant to complete the work that the Universal Century was created to do: establish humanity as a space-based species, not an Earth-based one.